# Error installing pydoop with pip on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install pydoop with pip on my Ubuntu 18.04 and keep getting an error "Failed building wheel for pydoop".

```
pip install pydoop
```

```
/bin/sh: 1: hadoop: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zqQz1I/pydoop/setup.py", line 368, in <module>
        zip_safe=False,
      File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zqQz1I/pydoop/setup.py", line 320, in run
        self.build_java()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zqQz1I/pydoop/setup.py", line 301, in build_java
        jb = JavaBuilder(self.build_temp, self.build_lib)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zqQz1I/pydoop/setup.py", line 199, in __init__
        self.java_libs = [JavaLib()]
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zqQz1I/pydoop/setup.py", line 183, in __init__
        self.classpath = pydoop.hadoop_classpath()
      File "pydoop/__init__.py", line 79, in hadoop_classpath
        return _PATH_FINDER.hadoop_classpath()
      File "pydoop/hadoop_utils.py", line 126, in hadoop_classpath
        "hadoop classpath --glob", shell=True, universal_newlines=True
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'hadoop classpath --glob' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

It seems as though it is not recognizing the hadoop command, however, whenever I use this in the command line there is no problem. I included the path to hadoop in the .bashrc file.

Comment: "*I included the path to hadoop in the .bashrc file.*" What exactly you've added in `.basrc`? Did you restart the shell or reread `.bashrc`? You don't use `sudo`?

Comment: I am not sure but isn't it using `/bin/sh` so it's not using `.bashrc` then?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, `sh` is not going to use `.bashrc`. Try adding the Hadoop binaries to your PATH, e.g., `export PATH="${hadoop_home}/bin:${hadoop_home}/sbin:${PATH}"`